# The structure of "cut himself a nice fat slash off"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parsing, structure

> Everybody is gonna cut himself a nice fat slash off John Does, eh?

I failed to comprehend how I parse the sentence. Especially, I'd like to  see what "off John Does" modifies.

My parsing is as follows:

Everybody (subject)
 is gonna cut(transitive verb chunk) himself (indirect object) a nice fat slash (direct object) off John Does (predicative complement)

Please correct me if I 'm wrong.

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: @James K It's from a movie "Meet John Doe" (1941)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a predicative complement of the subject. That is the noun or adjective that follows a linking verb in sentences like "John is good. John is a farmer".

In this sentence "off" acts as a preposition, indicating "disconnection or subtraction from".  So the phrase is a prepostional phrase. It acts like an adverb modifying the verb "cut".  It tells how to make the cut, and what (or who) to cut it from.  A simpler sentence with a similar structure might make this clearer.

> "Cut yourself a slice off the loaf"
>   "Take 20% off the price."

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm awfully sorry for me having been late.